# In which timeline was Gideon created in The Flash?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In Season 1 of *The Flash* we see Eobard Thawne having conversations with Gideon and when Team Flash discovered Gideon she tells Barry Allen  "I will obey all your commands because you created me".

Barry Allen is a forensic lab scientist and has no knowledge of Software and Artificial intelligence, then is it some other timeline where Gideon is created?

Eobard Thawne came back in time and killed Barry's mother and the original Harrison Wells so that means there exists a timeline where Nora and Harry are still alive and Barry ends up being a software specialist speedster in order to create Gideon.

Before killing the original Harrison Wells, Eobard Thawne tells him that in the year 2020 you SUCCESSFULLY started the particle accelerator which changed the world.

So is it that in that timeline Flash was created late in 2020 with Nora and Harrison both alive?